# How to parse shortcodes within returned content

Tags: shortcode, post-content

I'm using Visual Composer, but I think it has more to do with WordPress than VC ;-)
I did a shortcode (with the [VC API](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Adding+Custom+Shortcode+to+Grid+Builder)) to get the content of a post.
Here it is (in functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'vc_grid_item_shortcodes', 'my_module_add_grid_shortcodes' );
function my_module_add_grid_shortcodes( $shortcodes ) {
    $shortcodes['vc_post_id'] = array(
 'name' => __( 'Post content', 'fluidtopics' ),
 'base' => 'vc_post_content',
 'category' => __( 'Content', 'fluidtopics' ),
 'description' => __( 'Show current post content', 'fluidtopics' ),
 'post_type' => Vc_Grid_Item_Editor::postType(),
);

return $shortcodes;
}

add_shortcode( 'vc_post_content', 'vc_post_content_render' );
function vc_post_content_render() {
return '{{ post_data:post_content }}';
}
```

The content is really rendered. The layout provided by VC is achieved through shortcodes too... which are not parsed and displayed with the content.
I wonder if it's possible to get these shortcodes parsed ?

This can be viewed here: https://www.fluidtopics.com/whats-new-2/ (third tab, you'll see [vc_row] etc.)

Thanks a lot for any help !

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code given by the VC team. And it works.

```
// display content in grid
add_filter( 'vc_grid_item_shortcodes', 'my_module_add_grid_shortcodes' );
function my_module_add_grid_shortcodes( $shortcodes ) {
$shortcodes['vc_post_content'] = array(
    'name' => __( 'Post content', 'fluidtopics' ),
    'base' => 'vc_post_content',
    'category' => __( 'Content', 'fluidtopics' ),
    'description' => __( 'Show current post content', 'fluidtopics' ),
    'post_type' => Vc_Grid_Item_Editor::postType(),
);

return $shortcodes;
}

add_shortcode( 'vc_post_content', 'vc_post_content_render' );
function vc_post_content_render() {
return '{{ do_shortcode_post_content }}';
}

add_filter( 'vc_gitem_template_attribute_do_shortcode_post_content', 'vc_gitem_template_attribute_do_shortcode_post_content', 10, 2 );

function vc_gitem_template_attribute_do_shortcode_post_content( $value, $data ) {
/**
 * @var null|Wp_Post $post ;
 * @var string $data ;
 */
extract( array_merge( array(
    'post' => null,
    'data' => '',
), $data ) );
$atts_extended = array();
parse_str( $data, $atts_extended );

WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes();

$output = do_shortcode( $post->post_content );
ob_start();
//  do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' );
//  wp_print_styles();
//  wp_print_scripts();
//  wp_print_footer_scripts();
$output .= ob_get_clean();

return $output;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try `do_shortcode()` - [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

```
add_shortcode( 'vc_post_content', 'vc_post_content_render' );
function vc_post_content_render() {
return do_shortcode('{{ post_data:post_content }}');
}
```

That should filter out the remaining shortcodes within the returned content.

Comment: did this not work?

Comment: Sorry for the delay Douglas. And thank you for your answer. I did try this before and it doesn't work.